# Drupal Views Exposed filter ( Taxonomy )

Tags: taxonomy-terms, views

I have 3 fields ( Exposed filter ) 1 Country 2 State 3 City

When a respective Country is selected in the 1st field, I want the second filter ( Dropdown or autocompete ) to display states of the country selected in the 1st field & when this is done based on the state selection , I want the 3rd field to show only the cities belonging to the state selected in the second field.

How can this be done ? any help ?

Comment: Possibly related: [Drupal Views Exposed Filter ( Creating seperate filters for parent , child & grandchild )](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/q/158675/1190)

Answer (score 0):

If you have arranged your taxonomy in a hierarchical manner, then you can use the Hierarchical Select module:

https://www.drupal.org/project/hierarchical_select

Comment: i have seen hierarchical select & simple hierarchical select, these populate fields according to selection,while what I am looking for is 3 fields which are already there some thing like the screen shot here https://www.drupal.org/files/hierarchical_filters.png can you guide , please

Comment: I am almost certain that Hierarchical Select can be configured to do what you are describing.  In fact, there is an example of three drop-downs w/ defaults on the demo site: http://wimleers.com/demo/hierarchical-select/taxonomy