# Drupal Views Exposed Filter ( Creating seperate filters for parent , child & grandchild )

Tags: taxonomy-terms, views

How can one achieve following in exposed fliters

FILTER ONE (PARENT) FILTER TWO ( CHILD ) FILTER THREE ( GRAND CHILD )..

I dont want SHS or HS,

Please guide.

Comment: Possibly related: [Drupal Views Exposed filter ( Taxonomy )](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/q/158394/1190)